# Automatic date on InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm trying to make my own planner or journal using InDesign. I was wondering if there is any way I can make the date go 'up' automatically. So that I can add pages, based on a master for example, without having to put each date manually on the separate pages.

Thank you!

Comment: Put a page number and make new chapter as new month. Or use Caldendar Wizard plugin. It will create exactly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Without doing a complete data merge from a spreadsheet, you could use Indesign's built in Chapter / Section / Page markers from the master templates.

There's a tutorial here from Adobe:
[Numbering Pages - Chapters - Sections](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/numbering-pages-chapters-sections.html)

Basically, you would want to set your sections titled as the different months, and add the number of pages each month has from your master pages. If this isn't clear, I can give you a tutorial specifically for your situation.